# Force "soft" update of fields with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an application, call it a "form-filler" that works with many, many sites using Jquery to automatically update fields.

Pseudo Code:

1. Inject Jquery into the webpage
2. Discover the required form.
3. Update the values, e.g.,

```
$(document).ready(function) {
   $('#id').val("some value");
}
```

I have a new customer who is using Angularjs and this model breaks down as the $scope is obviously being updated "out-of-band".  I don't have access to the third party source to make changes, so I was wondering if it is possibly to get a jQuery update to trigger an Angularjs update?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [angular.element()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) to get a hold of the scope and the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController):

```js
var value = 'theNewValue';
var el = angular.element($('#name'));

el.scope().$apply(function(){
  el.val(value);
  el.controller('ngModel').$setViewValue(el.val());
});
```

Here is a simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OJQQmanwQoFQSgECuqal?p=preview

Comment: This does look much cleaner +1

Comment: As you can see from the plunker it doesn't happen in my example, so you're probably doing something different. It looks like you're calling this code from within another $apply cycle, remove the  `el.scope().$apply(function(){` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing on the other responses, I'd suggest to use `$timeout` instead of `$apply` to avoid problems with the digest phase.

Like in @liviu-t response, get hold of the $timeout service by means of the $element's injector. Then use it as it was a nextTick() function. It is in fact (with second argument 0 or missing) almost equivalent to `nextTick()`, with the difference that it always runs its argument in the digest phase, unlike $apply, which must be called *outside* of the digest.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tad complicated depending on the actual case. My solution assumes that the elements are available on dom ready and not loaded by angular using partials. [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/za1CnsLK8DCKFBj2XhSx?p=preview)

**JS**

```
function setAngularValue($elem, value) {
  var scope = $elem.scope();
  var ngModelName = $elem.attr('ng-model');
  if(ngModelName) {
    var $injector = $elem.injector();
    //get the parse service to use on the ng-model
    var $parse = $injector.get('$parse');
    var ngModel = $parse(ngModelName);
    scope.$apply(function() {
      //this will allow any ng-model value ex: my.object.value
      ngModel.assign(scope, value);
    });
  }
  else {
    //fallback if there is no model, weird case imho
    $elem.val(value);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $elem = angular.element('#myJqueryId');
  var value = 'some value';
  setAngularValue($elem, value);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Hello {{my.angular.model}}!</p>
<input id="myJqueryId" ng-model="my.angular.model"></input>
```

**LINKS**

1. [$injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector)
2. [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse)